# Compiz RAM usage

Tags: 15.10, compiz

Is it normal for compiz to use ~280 Mb of RAM after several hours of running? 
It consumes around 100-120 Mb on startup and slowly increases up to 250-280 Mb. 
I have heard that this is too much for Unity. 
Running `unity --replace &`  didn't change anything.